# How to explicitly wait for the count of basket to be changed from zero to one using selenium -java when products are added to basket

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate adding products to basket in amazon and asserting to check if count of basket has been changed once items are added to basket .

So I am explicitly waiting till products are added ,however basket icon is already in page so my code is unable to fetch the count of basket after adding the product .

WebDriverWait waitDriver = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
     waitDriver.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("nav-cart-count")));

Answer (score 0):

If this concerns only no items -> some items, you can try waiting for the class `nav-cart-1` as it appears only when there are some items in the basket.

```
WebDriverWait waitDriver = new WebDriverWait(driver,30); 
waitDriver.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.css("span#nav-cart-count.nav-cart-1")));
```

But this will not work if you are interested in the exact count.

If you want to check exact count, you should use xpath with `text()` condition

```
    waitDriver.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text() = '1' and @id='nav-cart-count']")));
```